# Prevent fake location on iPhone : Location spoofing

Tags: iphone, location, spoofing

I search a way to prevent fake location on iPhone.

A possible solution is to check, if a non-exhaustive list of app is launch (Cydia .. etc). But can I do that ?

Thanks for all responses or approaches.

Comment: Anyone knows ? I'm not alone to get this issue ?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same situation. somebody help

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this too, where the phone sends the lonlat to a server, and I want to prevent people just POSTing any lonlat they choose (e.g. via `curl`). One idea is to also submit the available Wifi SSIDs along with the location, and if someone claims a location with an SSID list that differs substantially from others', flag that submission for review. Unfortunately iOS doesn't give you a way to obtain the list of available SSIDs. . . .